# How can i save a string in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, I have two questions:

1. how do I save something on the screen, even when I close the screen and open it again what I wrote is there;
2. How to create a delete button for each email and password

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

roots = Tk()
roots.title("Email's save")
roots.geometry("500x500")
roots.resizable(False, False)

"""
e = email
p = password
"""

e = Entry(roots)
e.grid(row=0, column=1)
e.focus_set()

p = Entry(roots, show="*")
p.grid(row=1, column=1)
p.focus_set()

textEmail = StringVar()
textPassword = StringVar()

def callback():
    textEmail.set(textEmail.get() + e.get() + "\n")
    textPassword.set(textPassword.get() + p.get() + "\n")

def EmailPassword():
    Label(roots, text="Email: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    Label(roots, text="Password: ").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Label(roots, text="Saved Email", font="Times 15 bold").grid(row=15, column=0)
    Label(roots, text="Password", font="Times 15 bold").grid(row=15, column=15)

    Label(roots, textvariable=textEmail).grid(row=20, column=0)
    Label(roots, textvariable=textPassword).grid(row=20, column=15)

    btn_save = Button(roots, text="Save", command= callback).grid(row=2, column=1, stick=E)

    roots.mainloop()

EmailPassword()
```

Comment: Try [SaveVar](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkmacosx/tree/master/tkmacosx#savevar). It is easy and simple way to save any value of any Tkinter variable and loads the values back when the app is reopened.

Comment: @Saad it doesn't seem cross-platform, it's in the package `tkmacosx`...

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519: Try it yourself [here](https://repl.it/@SaadMairaj/TreasuredSlipperySearchservice#main.py), run the program then type something in the `Entry` widget and then re-run the program. I think it works cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

> How to create a delete button for each email and password

First of all, it's best to store the widgets in variables, or else you won't be able to manage them later (e.g. editing the font/colour/contents/etc, removing the widget, etc). So instead of:

```
Label(...).grid(...)
```

It's better to do:

```
variableName = Label(...)
variableName.grid(...)
```

(You can't do `variableName = Label(...).grid(...)` because `grid`, `pack`, and `place` return None, instead of the widget.)

You can use the `destroy()` method to remove a widget:

`variableName.destroy()`

to delete the widget.

> how do I save something on the screen, even when I close the screen and open it again what I wrote is there;

You will probably need to use files for this. Just for a refresher, to write to a file:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as file:
    file.write('Stuff to write to the file.')
```

And to read from a file:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
```

Keep in mind that after running `file.read()` you **cannot** run `file.read()` again without re-`open()`ing the file. I learned this the hard way while programming a calculator.

One more thing...on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general), we prefer users to ask **one** question in **one** Stack Overflow question.

It just makes everything more organized. :D

Comment: I don't understand how I can make the delete button appear for each string, it is only appearing once, I want it, I have 10 emails, 10 delete buttons appear, one for each email, can you help me with this?

Comment: You would need to put multiple buttons. Maybe do whenever an email is added, it will put a delete button right beside? I can't give you all the answers or you won't learn as much 